# Calculate weak closure of a set

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Before anybody marks this as a duplicate, I would like to  remark that the answer given in duplicate questions is that of the weak *sequential* closure, and not the weak closure itself.

So I am asked to find the weak closure of the set $E = \{e^{imt} + me^{int}, 0 \leq m <n\}$ in $L^2 [-\pi , \pi]$. I have already found the weak sequential closure, which is $E \cup \{e_m : m  \in M\}$.

Now, I know the definition of weak closure. It is basically as follows: $x \notin \overline{E_w} \iff \exists U \subset L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ weakly open set containing $x$ , such that $ U \cap E = \emptyset$. The meaning of weakly open set, is that $U = \bigcap \{y : f(y-x) < \epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon$ and finitely many $f$.

I don't know how much this helps. I know that $L^2$ is Hilbert, so $f$ can only be of a specific form by the Riesz representation theorem. It is very difficult to calculate the weak closure because it is difficult to negate the statement of definition, or to think of candidates for the elements.Somebody needs to either tell me how to calculate it in another way, or a definition that is more flexible than this one.

Comment: what is $\phi$ in your equation?

Comment: $\phi$ is a set, the empty set. I don;t see what else it could be,  given it is a set.

Comment: Then why use phi? The symbol for the empty set is $\emptyset$

Comment: Well, I write that symbol almost like a $\phi$, so I thought I might as well go with $\phi$. On your request, I'll change it. But that apart, any opinion on the question ?

Comment: Okay, you know the weak sequential closure $E_1 = E \cup \{ e_m : m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $E$. What is the weak sequential closure $E_2$ of $E_1$? When you iterate the weak sequential closures, do you reach a fixed point? If so, when? Would that be a reasonable candidate for the weak closure of $E$?

Comment: Can you explain, from definition, what is the intuition behind wanting to iterate weak sequential closures? Because I think that after taking it once the set does not change, it is weakly sequentially closed after that.

Comment: The weak sequential closure of a set is contained in its weak closure. But taking the weak sequential closure is not an idempotent operation (this is one of the classical examples for that, $E_1$ is not weakly sequentially closed). Thus if you iterate it until you reached a fixed point, you get nearer to the weak closure with each step. Once you've reached a fixed point, you have something that might be weakly closed. Of course this is only a useful way to get to the weak closure in some special situations. But we're having a special situation here.

Comment: Oh! I see! For example, the second weak sequential closure would contain $0$, because it's the weak limit of $\{e_m\}$! But then it stops after that, so the answer would be the weak sequential closure union zero. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. $E_2 = E_1 \cup \{0\}$, and $E_2$ is weakly sequentially closed. Now try to show it's weakly closed. (Disclaimer, I'm not 100% sure it is, just reasonably sure.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your help so far. My final point is, why would you think of iterating the weak sequential closure? I know it is contained in the sequential closure, but why would iteration preserve weak closure? Furthermore, why was this a *special* case, and what are the other special cases, if any that you have seen in a problem or theorem's proof?

Comment: Let's denote the weak closure of a set $A$ by $c(A)$, and the weak sequential closure by $s(A)$. Then we have $A \subset s(A) \subset c(A)$ for all $A$. Since $c$ is an idempotent - and monotonic - operation, it follows that $s(A) \subset s(s(A)) \subset c(s(A)) \subset c(c(A)) = c(A)$. And so on, thus iterating $s$ never leads out of $c(A)$. This is a special case, since computing the (iterated) weak sequential closure(s) is rather easy, and it quickly stabilises. So we quickly get a weakly sequentially closed set $B$ with $E \subset B \subset c(E)$. $B$ is then a candidate for $c(E)$.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't recall any other special cases, where a) the weak sequential closure is distinct from the weak closure, and b) the weak sequential closure can be determined easily enough.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insight. I will try this myself. Meanwhile, you can post this as an answer if you like, but the discussion encompasses what I was looking for.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've found something interesting, and I  thought I should share it with you. Actually, while it's true that the set above is weakly sequentially closed, it isn't the weak closure, and the reason is this: consider $e_m+me_n$, then a weak neighbourhood of this is given by $\{ h \in H : \langle x_i , h-e_m-me_n\rangle < \epsilon\}$, for some finitely many  $x_i \in H$.Now, we know that $\langle x, e_l\rangle \to 0$ as $l \to \infty$ for all $x \in H$, but then $h$ would have to look like $e_l + e_m + me_n$ in that case, which is  not in the set. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You're looking at weak neighbourhoods of the wrong points. Take a $h\notin E_2$, and try to find a weak neighbourhood of $h$ not intersecting $E_2$. (That does work, see below, and indeed $E_2$ is the weak closure of $E$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A note on terminology up front: The operation

$$s \colon M \mapsto \bigl\{ x : \text{There is a sequence } (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ in } M \text{ with } x_n \rightharpoonup x\bigr\}$$

is not a closure operation in the usual sense [closure operations are idempotent], $s(M)$ is not necessarily weakly sequentially closed. Therefore it may create confusion to call $s(M)$ the weak sequential closure of $M$, one may expect the weak sequential closure of $M$ would be the smallest weakly sequentially closed set containing $M$. Nevertheless, it is not unusual that $s(M)$ is called the weak sequential closure of $M$ (e.g. Rudin does so in exercise 9 of chapter 3 of his *Functional Analysis*).

Now it is an easily verified fact that a weakly closed set is weakly sequentially closed (in any topological space closed subsets are sequentially closed, but the converse does not necessarily hold). Therefore we always have

$$M \subset s(M) \subset \operatorname{cl}_{w} (M)$$

(where $\operatorname{cl}_w$ denotes the weak closure), and since the weak closure operator is monotone (that is, $A \subset B \implies \operatorname{cl}_w(A) \subset \operatorname{cl}_w(B)$) and idempotent, even $s^k(M) \subset \operatorname{cl}_w (M)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (one can go beyond $\mathbb{N}$, this inclusion holds for all ordinals $k$, but we don't need that here). Thus in cases where

- the weak sequential closures are easy to determine, and
- the iteration of $s$ soon leads to a fixed point,

iterating the weak sequential closure can help to determine the weak closure. Once you've reached a fixed point of $s$, i.e. a weakly sequentially closed set, you have a set that *may* be weakly closed. If it isn't, it often is still easier to determine the weak closure than from the original set.

Here we have such a situation,

$$E_1 := s(E) = E \cup \{ e_m : m \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

($e_0$ already belongs to $E$, but there's no harm in listing it twice), and it's not hard to find

$$E_2 := s(E_1) = E_1 \cup \{0\}$$

(since $e_m \rightharpoonup 0$), and that $E_2$ is weakly sequentially closed. Since $E_2$ is countable, there is reasonable hope that it is also weakly closed. To check that, we choose an arbitrary $x \notin E_2$, and see whether we can find a weak neighbourhood of $x$ not intersecting $E_2$. Since $E_2 \subset F:= \overline{\operatorname{span}} \{ e_m : m \in \mathbb{N}\}$, it suffices to consider $x \in F$.

Since $x \neq 0$,

$$\kappa = \min \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : \langle x, e_n\rangle \neq 0\}$$

is well-defined. Let's assume the inner product is normalised so that $\lVert e_n\rVert = 1$ for all $n$ to avoid having to deal with a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$ everywhere.

If $\langle x, e_{\kappa}\rangle \neq 1$, let $\delta = \min \{ \lvert\langle x,e_{\kappa}\rangle,\, \lvert 1 - \langle x, e_{\kappa}\rangle\rvert,\, 1/2\}$. Then

$$V(\kappa; \delta) := \{ y : (0\leqslant \nu \leqslant \kappa) \implies (\lvert \langle y-x, e_{\nu}\rangle\rvert < \delta)\}$$

is a weak neighbourhood of $x$ not intersecting $E_2$. For $y \in V(\kappa; \delta)$, we have $\langle y, e_\kappa\rangle \notin \{0,1\}$ and $\langle y,e_\nu\rangle \neq 1$ for $0 \leqslant \nu < \kappa$, whereas for $z \in E_2$, we have $\langle z, e_\kappa\rangle \in \{0,1\}$ or there is a $\nu < \kappa$ with $\langle z, e_{\nu}\rangle = 1$ (then $z = e_\nu + \nu e_\kappa$).

If on the other hand $\langle x, e_{\kappa} \rangle = 1$, then, since $e_\kappa \in E_2$,

$$\lambda = \min \{ n > \kappa : \langle x, e_n\rangle \neq 0\}$$

is well-defined. If $\langle x, e_{\lambda}\rangle \neq \kappa$, let $\delta = \min \{ \lvert \langle x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert,\, \lvert \kappa - \langle x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert,\, 1/2\}$. Then

$$W(e_\kappa, e_\lambda; \delta) := \{ y : \lvert \langle y-x, e_\kappa\rangle \rvert < \delta,\, \lvert \langle y-x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert < \delta\}$$

is a weak neighbourhood of $x$ not intersecting $E_2$. For if $z \in E_2$ with $\lvert \langle z-x,e_\kappa\rangle\rvert < \delta$, then $\langle z,e_\kappa\rangle = 1$, and $z$ can only be one of $e_\kappa,\, e_1 + e_\kappa$, or $e_\kappa + \kappa e_\mu$ where $\mu > \kappa$. In all of these possibilities except for $z = e_\kappa + \kappa e_\lambda$, we have $\langle z, e_\lambda\rangle = 0$ and hence

$$\lvert \langle z - x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert = \lvert \langle x, e_\lambda\rangle \rvert \geqslant \delta,$$

whence $z \notin W(e_\kappa, e_\lambda; \delta)$. And for $z = e_\kappa + \kappa e_\lambda$, we have

$$\lvert \langle z-x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert = \lvert \kappa - \langle x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert \geqslant \delta,$$

so $z \notin W(e_\kappa, e_\lambda; \delta)$ also in this case.

It remains to consider the case $\langle x, e_\kappa\rangle = 1$ and $\langle x, e_\lambda\rangle = \kappa$. Then, since $x \neq e_\kappa + \kappa e_\lambda$,

$$\mu = \min \{ n > \lambda : \langle x, e_n\rangle \neq 0\}$$

is well-defined. Let $\delta = \min \{ \lvert \langle x, e_\mu\rangle\rvert,\, 1/2\}$. Then

$$W(e_\kappa, e_\lambda, e_\mu; \delta) = \{ y : \lvert\langle y-x, e_\kappa\rangle\rvert < \delta,\, \lvert\langle y-x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert < \delta,\, \lvert\langle y-x, e_\mu\rangle\rvert < \delta\}$$

is a weak neighbourhood of $x$ not intersecting $E_2$. For the only $z\in E_2$ with $\lvert\langle z-x,e_\kappa\rangle\rvert < \delta$ and $\lvert \langle z-x, e_\lambda\rangle\rvert < \delta$ is $z = e_\kappa + \kappa e_\lambda$, and then we have $\langle z, e_\mu\rangle = 0$ whence

$$\lvert\langle z-x, e_\mu\rangle\rvert = \lvert\langle x, e_\mu\rangle\rvert \geqslant \delta.$$

Thus $\operatorname{cl}_w (E) = E_2$ is proven.

Comment: Wow. I , well, this question is worth just $2$ marks in a twenty mark test online. Says a fair about standards then. Thank you.